# Android - email link opens Web browser instead of my application on Android OS 4.0+

Tags: android, email, browser, hyperlink

I need to open my application when user clicks on a link in email. I found many answers on stackoverflow and [this answer by skorulis in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697899/how-to-send-email-with-link-to-open-android-application) worked for me on Android versions less then 4.0, but on the versions above 4.0 the links opens in the web browser instead of the app.