# Sending Emails with links in android

Tags: android, email, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email with link to open Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697899/how-to-send-email-with-link-to-open-android-application)

I'm making an Android which needs to send an email out which contains two links. I've attempted this by sending an intent with a HTML formatted email.

This works fine if the user uses the inbuilt Gmail client, however when tested on the android email client it seems to strip out the links.

I don't want to force the user to have to use the Gmail client, is there an alternative way to include links in an email, which will work with the inbuilt email client?

Comment: @Ramkiran This is a problem with the gmail client receiving the email, where it strips the link if the link does not start with http/https. My problem is they are getting stripped, when it is sent regardless of the scheme used and the client receiving the email.